# What happened to Tyrell Wellick?

Tags: mr-robot

Tyrell Wellick wasn't shown in the whole of last episode of Mr Robot. Although, Elliot concluded that he might have killed him, I don't believe that. What really happened to him?

Comment: The short answer is that we don't know yet!

Comment: It's all speculation at this point, but I believe Tyrell and Elliot are actually the same person.

Comment: @Dannie Then Gideon and Tyrell's wife would have noticed that.

Comment: I'm almost certain the wife is playing him, I mean that was an extremely strange conversation, also notice her expression when he doesn't understand danish. As for Gideon, it's damn near impossibly to say when Elliot is hallucinating. He's quite mad as they say ;)

Comment: @Dannie Touché. I hope Tyrell isnt Elliot. I would be disappointed.

Comment: It's also important to note how Tyrell's wife reacted to Elliot: she lied about her husband, then attempted to speak Swedish or Danish to him.  If Elliot *is* Tyrell, her attitude might make sense if she's aware of his mental issues and didn't know which personality she was talking to at the time.  Alternatively, Tyrell could be another friend/sibling that Elliot completely forgot about, and that's why she behaved so strangely towards him.

Comment: @Liesmith I think Joanna might be Elliott's friend. Through her he met Tyrell. This might explain the proposed 'big' role for Joanna next season.

Comment: @user295175 That's good to hear; I really like that actress' performance.  I'm kind of hoping that all the characters are in Elliot's head and he's actually hallucinating the world that we see after he was stabbed by a Glarghk Guhl Kashmas’nik.

Comment: Joanna would have stabbed Elliot/Tyrell to death if they were the same person. Maybe she killed Tyrell and that's why Elliot can't find him (and why she acts so strange). Plus, Gideon and Tyrell meet at Tyrell's office right before Tyrell tells his secretary that he won't meet with the police.

Comment: Tyrell was the man in the fsociety mask in the finale, I believe. Look at the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyrell played Elliot - plain and simple. 
Got the info on the plan/hack. Sold out Elliot and fsociety to the CEO to get himself back into the VIP club. I think the reason we don't see him is that he wanted to 'drop off the radar' while the shit hit the fan. There's zero chance he is dead.He is notable character to get rid of in season 1 (especially doing so off-screen). What's not clear yet is if Tyrell is a pure Judas/betrayer role or some kind of 'dark knight', double-agent thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the beginning of the season there has been three major character Elliot, Mr Robot and Tyrell Wellick. We anticipated the analogy of the relationship and what will be the connection between them (that Mr Robot was in his mind), as most of the people would have also guessed it.

Now the character left- Tyrell Wellick. Yours answer is contained in his qoute:-

"Give a man a gun and he'll rob a bank. Give a man a bank and he'll rob the world."

Since the beginning, as Elliot said he's being watched. Now the anticipations are:-

He was the master-mind of the whole plan, he played with the mind of Elliot, he made Elliot do what he wanted him to do (he wants to  rob the world). But all the things did not go as he planned. So he kills Sharon and disappears (also from the mind of Elliot, otherwise Elliot would be able to figure out the whole scam). In short, Tyrell or may be her wife (she handles the situation very well) created the Mr Robot and these two character are going be there till the end of the whole series.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that the most rational character in the series, Gideon, was both managing and reporting to the same physical person. Tyrell's wife is a manipulative sociopath, sort of like the protagonist, but that was just her standard tactical behavior, not a lead that she's somehow puppeteering him all along. Everyone refers to both Elliot and Tyrell as separate people, while only Elliot and Tyrell encounter Mr. Robot. How Tyrell can see this hallucination without being the same person as Elliot is a mystery. except that he may have been talking to Elliot, who was at that time in the Mr. Robot persona, and the show depicted it as such.

Tyrell might be dead but it's underwhelming; Whiterose and the CEO were talking about dealing with the one responsible, it might be him they are discussing. We could be in for a Bigger Bad type situation in season 2 with Tyrell removed from the show. But it's unlikely. Dealt with could mean a number of things. Probably being promoted again was not it.

If Tyrell has a Batman Gambit in store, that's the most likely scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Tyrell was shot to death by Mr. Robot, probably right after Mr. Robot and he pulled the trigger on [5/9](http://mrrobot.wikia.com/wiki/Five/Nine_Hack). His body was in the trunk of his own SUV where the parking attendant that Joanna had killed last saw Elliot.

This is revealed in eps2.5_h4ndshake.sme (S2E7) when Mr. Robot tells Elliot right before Elliot fixes Ray's Tor node.

Romero was seen being shot to death by Mr. Robot, but perhaps Mr. Robot recalls these events incorrectly and he actually shot Tyrell. If so, then it does stand to justice that the Dark Army killed Romero, as thought by Darlene and Mobley (Trenton is also there at the time, but she says nothing about Romero). It seems impossible that Mr. Robot could have shot Romero to death unless Romero was also in prison with Elliot. Mobley found Romero's body, not some prisoner guard.

Comment: Please don't put questions in answers. If you have a new question to ask, please post it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button in the top right.

Comment: You can still see the original text in the [revision history](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/59499/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Since s03e03, we now know. Tyrell wanted to join Elliot / Mr. Robot to get back at E-Corp, Mr. Robot attempts to shoot him but fails, which Tyrell explains it as divine intervention, and convinces him he has a part to play in the plan to bring down E-Corp. At this point the Dark Army barges with guns to spirit Tyrell away to private land before the FBI could catch him.

tl;dr: on Dark Army land, chopping wood.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Tyrell may have been a figure of Elliot's broken reality as he is only ever seen talking to people such as Elliot or Mr. Robot... then again there is the time when he was at the party, wanted to be questioned by the police and when he talked to Gideon... It's hard to say what happened to him but of anything I don't think he is dead